# how to remove the warnings published on jenkins, also how to configure those warnings?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

[image]

when i tried to restart manually it say Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured.
As i cant restart it I am unable to update the plugins .
I tried to uninstall extra plugins but i was unable to resolve it .
could you guys explain how to resolve it so that i can create and run jobs .

Comment: 1) Those are warnings, you can dismiss the dialog. While you should update, you can also suppress the warnings (configure what warnings are shown). 2) if you run from the command line, Jenkins cannot restart (only when as a set ice); just exit and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those warnings are a blocker to run a job.

If you can't update the plugins you can try to update the jenkins biany/image itself.